# Update list items inside a list (matrix)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to update all list items that are inside a list. Better to say it's a matrix. I'm building it like that:
`grids = [["#"] * grid_size for _ in range(grid_size)]`

Output if my grid for a size 4:

```
[['#', '#', '#', '#'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '#'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '#'],
 ['#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

Next to that I have a list of dictionaries with several words inside. Code: `all_words = [x for x in words]`

Output of all words:

```
...
...
 {'definition': 'Maladie virale caractérisée par une éruption de vésicules '
                'disposées sur le trajet des nerfs sensitifs.',
  'word': 'ZONA',
  'word_length': Decimal('4')},
 {'definition': "Partie d'une surface sphérique comprise entre deux plans "
                'parallèles.',
  'word': 'ZONE',
  'word_length': Decimal('4')},
 {'definition': 'Musique de danse très rythmée, originaire de la Martinique.',
  'word': 'ZOUK',
  'word_length': Decimal('4')},
 {'definition': 'Naïf, niais.', 'word': 'ZOZO', 'word_length': Decimal('4')}]
```

What I would like to do is to replace the "#" in the matrix in order to add the 'word' that are in my dictionaries. Here for the example 'ZONA', 'ZONE', 'ZOUK' and 'ZOZO' that are my four last words.

Desired output:

```
[['Z', 'O', 'N', 'A'],
 ['Z', 'O', 'N', 'E'],
 ['Z', 'O', 'U', 'K'],
 ['Z', 'O', 'Z', 'O']]
```

The best would be of course to add only these four words so that the matrix doesn't expand more than it is. I tried with a list comprehension inside another list comprehension but I'm messing everything up...

Thanks a lot  for your help !
Btv-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you have right now

```
all_words = [ {'definition': 'Maladie virale caracterisee par une eruption de vesicules '
    ...:                 'disposees sur le trajet des nerfs sensitifs.',
    ...:   'word': 'ZONA',
    ...:   'word_length': Decimal('4')},
    ...:  {'definition': "Partie d'une surface spherique comprise entre deux plans "
    ...:                 'paralleles.',
    ...:   'word': 'ZONE',
    ...:   'word_length': Decimal('4')},
    ...:  {'definition': 'Musique de danse tres rythmee, originaire de la Martinique.',
    ...:   'word': 'ZOUK',
    ...:   'word_length': Decimal('4')},
    ...:  {'definition': 'Naif, niais.', 'word': 'ZOZO', 'word_length': Decimal('4')}]
```

First get a list of only the words with the correct length

```
only_words = [word["word"] for word in all_words if len(word["word"]) == 4]
```

Then use list() to make the word into a list of individual letters

```
[list(word) for word in only_words[:4]]

[['Z', 'O', 'N', 'A'],
 ['Z', 'O', 'N', 'E'],
 ['Z', 'O', 'U', 'K'],
 ['Z', 'O', 'Z', 'O']]
```

Edit: I have added an if statement into the first list comp to filter words by their length. I see you have a "word_length" key but I'm unfamiliar with the Decimal() thing.

In the second list comp i have used list slicing to take the first n words only

Comment: Hi Edward thanks for your answer it does work but partly regarding my problem. I think I wasn't clear for my dictionaries, I have loads of them, not only 4. So your solution works but I have a massive matrix with all my words (around 1,000). Would you have a workaround to take the number of words that matches the size of my matrix ? Here my matrix is 4X4, so I only need 4 words. But let's say my matrix is 8X8 then I would need 8 words to fill my matrix

Comment: I have made an edit which I think is what you're looking for. Basically just filtering out the words by length and then taking the first n words to make the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You could typecast the word to list using `list()` directly to create a 2D list instead of replacing the hash in the created list.

```
all_words = ['ZONA' , 'ZONE', 'ZOUK', 'ZOZO']
print([list(word) for word in all_words])
```

Output:

```
[['Z', 'O', 'N', 'A'], ['Z', 'O', 'N', 'E'], ['Z', 'O', 'U', 'K'], ['Z', 'O', 'Z', 'O']]
```